# How to pass variable to tile (tiles library)

Tags: java, jsp, tiles

I handle templates of my application using tiles library.

tile.xml:

```
<definition name="template1" template="/WEB-INF/template/default/template1.jsp">
   ...
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/menu.jsp" />
   ...
</definition>
```

template1.jsp

```
<html>
    <body>   
        ...         
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />                   
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />  
        ...                 
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have to insert to tiles "menu". Since I have to dinamically print different menu inside "menu.jsp", how can I send 2 different variables to the 2 different tiles "menu"?

To be clearer

```
   <html>
        <body>   
            ...         
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /> <--- here I should pass a variable called menu1                   
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /> <--- here I should pass a variable called menu2                    
            ...                 
        </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks everybody

Comment: https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/nesting-extending.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two templates

```
<definition name="template1" template="/WEB-INF/template/default/template1.jsp">
   ...
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/menu1.jsp" />
   ...
</definition>

<definition name="template2" template="/WEB-INF/template/default/template1.jsp">
   ...
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/menu2.jsp" />
   ...
</definition>

<html>
    <body>   
        ...         
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />                   
        ...                 
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update**

You can use this approach too

```
<definition name="menu1" template="menu.jsp">
   ...
  <put name="header.tile" value="headerMenu1.jsp" />
   ...
</definition>

<definition name="menu2" template="menu.jsp">
   ...
  <put name="header.tile" value="headerMenu2.jsp" />
   ...
</definition>
```

In the `menu.jsp`

```
<tiles:insert attribute="header.tile" />
```

Comment: This way I should create 2 "menu.jsp" and I should make double work to maintain them. I want to have a single menu.jsp page and pass different variabile to it.